# The edittext of the fragment doesn't get refreshed on button click

Tags: java, android, button, android-fragments

I have managed to access the database and the radiobuttons of other fragments or buttonclick but when I try to setText of EditText, the current fragment doesn't get refreshed. I have tried invalidate, postInvalidate and refreshDrawableState without success. Any suggestions?

```
public static class Tsiatisto extends Fragment
{       
public Tsiatisto() {}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{                   
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tsiatisto, container, false);

mViews.add(inflater.inflate(R.layout.tsiatisto, container));

DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());         

try 
{
myDbHelper.createDataBase(); 
myDbHelper.openDataBase();
}catch(IOException ioe) 
{ 
throw new Error("Unable to create database"); 
}        

final SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getDB();       

//Cursor cursor =  db.query("Tsiatista ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", new String[] { "*" }, null, null, null, null, null);

final View button = rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonGo);
button.setOnClickListener(
new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
View fs;
RadioGroup rg;
int selectedId;
RadioButton rb;

fs = (View) mViews.get(0);
rg = (RadioGroup) fs.findViewById(R.id.radioGroupFS);
selectedId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
rb = (RadioButton) fs.findViewById(selectedId);
funnySerious = (String) rb.getText();  

fs = (View) mViews.get(1);
rg = (RadioGroup) fs.findViewById(R.id.radioGroupMF);
selectedId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
rb = (RadioButton) fs.findViewById(selectedId);
malefemale = (String) rb.getText();  

fs = (View) mViews.get(2);
rg = (RadioGroup) fs.findViewById(R.id.radioGroupDC);
selectedId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
rb = (RadioButton) fs.findViewById(selectedId);
dirtyclean = (String) rb.getText();  

Cursor cursor =  db.rawQuery("SELECT Verse FROM Tsiatista WHERE FunnySerious = '" + funnySerious + "' AND (MaleFemale = '" + malefemale + "' OR MaleFemale = 'Both')", null);

if(cursor.moveToFirst())
{                   
String verse = (String) cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Verse"));

EditText et = (EditText) mViews.get(3).findViewById(R.id.tsiatistoTxt);
et.setText(verse);

cursor.close();

View vv = mViews.get(3);
//vv.();
//vv.postInvalidate();
//vv.refreshDrawableState();
//View ve = (View) mViews.get(3).findViewById(R.id.tsiatistoTxt);
//ve.removeAllViews();
//ve.refreshDrawableState();

}   

}
}
);

return rootView;
}       
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using the `getView()` method call instead of `get(index);` I am not sure that you are getting the right reference to the UI Element. Example `EditText myEditText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.myEditText);`

Comment: I would also suggest moving all of this code out of the `onCreateView()` method and moving it into onActivityCreated() or onViewCreated(). I believe the onCreateView method is meant to do the bare minumum UI inflation, and referencing Elements in this method can be quite taxing and not exactly reliable.